# Fail to pass values using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I can echo the value of the first session variable, but fail to echo the next value using `$_SESSION`, any idea?

```
<?php
//page 1
session_start(); 

$vvvvv = $_POST['vaccineid'];
$_SESSION['vaccineidno'] = $vvvvv;

$qq = $_POST['vaccinename1'];
$_SESSION['vaccinenamet'] = $qq; 

<!-- This is the html-->
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name = "vaccineid[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccineid'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name = "vaccinename1[]" value="<?php echo $row['vaccinename1'] ?>">
  </td>
</tr>

<?php
//page 2
session_start(); 
$vvv = $_SESSION ['vaccineidno'];
echo $vvv;

$qq = $_SESSION ['vaccinenamet'];
echo $qq;
?>
```

Comment: any errors in the PHP errorlog?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: vaccinenamet in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\June21\addnewdosage1.php on line 24

Comment: in an effort to debug, on page 1 try setting `$_SESSION['vaccines']=$_POST;` and on page 2 `print_r( $_SESSION['vaccines'] );` ~ does this session variable contain all the POST data?

Comment: not all, just the first one and the submit ,i.e. Array ( [vaccineid] => VI 1471 [submit] => Confirm )

Comment: can you add your complete html form?

Comment: you have `    $vvv = $_SESSION ['vaccineidno'];` where as you need it to be `    $vvv = $_SESSION['vaccineidno'];` remove the space after $_SESSION.

Comment: the space should not affect anything in this instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php
//page 1
session_start(); 

$vvvvv = '10';
$_SESSION['vaccineidno'] = $vvvvv;

$qq = '11';
$_SESSION['vaccinenamet'] = $qq; 
?>
<!-- This is the html-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccineid[]" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "vaccinename1[]" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
    //page 2 
    $vvv = $_SESSION['vaccineidno'];
     echo $vvv;

     $qq = $_SESSION['vaccinenamet'];
     echo $qq;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is failing to set particular session variables - seeing the entire code would offer greater chance to see why it is failing but in the meantime consider the following single-page example.

Incidentally, the test here is to show that the values that are POSTed are ALL stored - rather than as array values as in original question they are simple text - using the array notation for fieldnames also works.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $svar = 'vaccines';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) $_SESSION[ $svar ]=$_POST;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Sessions and POST data - vaccines</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){
                echo '<pre>',print_r( $_SESSION[ $svar ],true ),'</pre>';
            }
        ?>
        <form name='vaccines' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='vaccine-id' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='vaccine-name' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dose</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='vaccine-dose' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='vaccine-price' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><input type='submit' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```